# How do I sync supplier's live stock database into Magento 2

Tags: product, magento2, database, magento-community

I am noob in Magento, my boss asks me to synchronize products, prices and quantities with the suppliers database on a daily basis.
We can have different sources.

Question is how can I access this data and integrate this into Magento 2 CE?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to write script, which will read data from supplier DB and then update product prices and stock info on Magento side using [web APIs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html). Some suggestions:

- REST is simpler than SOAP for integration
- Use [admin token-based authentication](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0//get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html)
- Documentation for all REST endpoints can be found [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html). The following ones should be useful in your case: `catalogProductRepositoryV1`, `catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1`

Comment: I think that a script must be in a Module. Then I need to create a Module like @AlexPaliarush said.